# Bulk Importing Text Files To MySQL with Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am importing text files that are 50,000 lines each in a folder, with a batch file. The batch file currently imports each file 1 by 1 but slows down a LOT over time. But if I close it and open it again it starts off fast again then slows down over time. I am wondering if anyone has any ideas to keep the speed so I can run it without checking it often.

I have tried making it delete the file it imports after It's done importing it, but am not experienced in batch enough to test that.

```
FOR %%f IN (*.txt) DO "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin/mysql.exe" -u root --password=passhere -D databasename -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/Newfolder/dd/%%f' IGNORE INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "sqlfile=loadData.sql"
set "folder=D:/Newfolder/dd"

(
    set "commit="
    echo BEGIN;

    for %%f in ("%folder%/*.txt") do (
        echo LOAD DATA INFILE '%folder%/%%~nxf' IGNORE INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
        set "commit=defined"
    )

    echo COMMIT;
) > "%sqlfile%"

if defined commit (
    "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin/mysql.exe" -u root --password=passhere -D databasename < "%sqlfile%"
)
```

My knowledge with MySQL syntax is little though
I know SQLite so the methods may be similar.

You may find that [Transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) are quicker if
you have many statements to process.

This code will create a sql file with the
transactional `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` statements.
Sql statements in a transaction will be treated
as a complete batch.
This means the database will lock and open once,
perform the transaction of sql statements,
and then will unlock and close the database.

If the variable named `commit` is not defined,
then `mysql.exe` will not run as no sql statements
were echoed to the sql file.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm, but I did have 1 error with it that I solved. I had to change `-e < "%sqlfile%"` to `< "%sqlfile%"`. but other than that it works great! Thanks again.

Comment: I removed the `-e` from the answer, thanks for the error information. Awesome that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's give this a try.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_sqlcmd=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe"
set cnt=1
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
     set id=%%i
     call :check
)

:check
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "mysql"') do set procs=%%a
if !procs! leq 20 (
    if not "!id!"=="%0" "%_sqlcmd" -u root --password=passhere -D databasename -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\Newfolder\dd\!id!' IGNORE INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
    set /a cnt+=1
) else (
    goto check
)
echo del /Q *.txt
```

It will kick of nine `mysql` processes, if one (or more) closes, it will start up more until we reach 20 processes again. (You can increase/decrease the process count you want to allow) This way, you will not start too many `mysql` processes at once which will eventually just consume all the memory and CPU.

As for the delete portion, you will notice the line of code at the end of the file `echo del /Q *.txt` This will purely `echo` the delete command of all `txt` files in the folder, ONLY once the script completed the entire run, if you are 100% sure that you want to delete the file after it completed, then just remove `echo` from that line, just be very aware that if you remove it, it will then delete all files.

Comment: @Compo Thanks, I am fine with the edit. the parenthesis are all good.